# Fighting the "Bleachies" (?) on a Norse-style planet with Valkyries (1960s–1970s novel)

Tags: story-identification, novel

I'm looking for the name of a 1960's or early 70's SF novel/novels in which the hero fought enemies called Bleachies (I think). One part had the hero and friends fighting on a Norse style planet. When the combatants were killed they were retrieved by Valkyries and revived.

Comment: We're going to need some more details, take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) and [edit] in any more details

Comment: Is the whole story set on a "Norse style planet" (whatever that is), or does the story involve interplanetary travel?